# Internal server error on "Go get your next badge" link

Tags: bug, badge-progress

[image]

When I click on **Go get it**, and after 30 secs, an internal error occurs.

The offending link is: `http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent&hideReview=on&minScore=0`

I can reproduce the error clicking the link again, not sure if it's just me.

Comment: I have that error too, same badge, also error page after 30s. _its reproducable_

Comment: I don't get that error but I am getting sent to my next tag which has a description of "DO NOT USE THIS TAG". And I'm 98% there :(

Comment: First noticed this around a month ago actually, seems to be intermittent though (same badge)

Comment: Perhaps SO doesn't want you to *Go get* your badge.

Comment: Furthermore a "down for maintenance" page is displayed once a few request with that faulty button are sent - see  meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327309/click-on-the-go-get-it-button-in-badge-description-displays-an-error-page

Comment: Why isn't the above link recognized as such and shortened? eg. https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=meta+stack+overflow&oq=meta+s&gs_l=hp.1.0.35i39l2j0i67j0i20l2j0l5.1049.1685.0.3120.7.7.0.0.0.0.117.515.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..1.5.455.0..0i131j0i10i67.5Ghmir8RgQM